# how to trim the specific lines starting and ending with character in a string in java

Tags: regex, java-8

I have stored the multiline string in java as shown in code below it shows the output as :

> aa
>
> bb
>
> hhh me $ hdddhd hhhdhhdhh
>
> hrx
>
> $
>
> dddsss

I dont need the line starting with hhh me $ and in between lines and upto $.

I need to get output as

> aa
>
> bb
>
> hrx
>
> dddsss

I have tried like this on eclipse

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class dummyFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String line = new StringBuilder()
            .append("aa\n\n")
            .append("bb\n\n")
            .append("hhh me $ hdddhd hhhdhhdhh\n\n")
            .append("hrx\n\n")
            .append("$\n\n")
            .append("dddsss")  
            .toString();
    System.out.println(line);

    String pattern = "hhh me (.)";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

    if (m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }

    if (line.contains("hhh me "+ m.group(1)))
    {
        line.replace(
                line.substring(
                        line.indexOf("banner mod " +m.group(1)),
                        line.lastIndexOf(m.group(1))+1
                    ),
                    ""
                )
                .replace("\n\n", "\n");
    }
    System.out.println(line);

}
```

}

Could some one please help ??

Comment: If you don't want anything up till the closing $ sign, then why do you want the `hrx` line in the output? That falls between the 2 dollar signs...

Answer (score 1):

Phew, that was a fun one (if you're insane like me!)

```
(?!.*?\$.*?)^.+?(?:\n\n|$).*?
```

You'll need the regex options `global` and `multiline`. For most regex instances that's just a matter of formatting it like:

```
/(?!.*?\$.*?)^.+?(?:\n\n|$).*?/gm
```

However for Java there may be some options you need to supply, I'm not 100% sure.

That pattern will give you multiple matches, which you can glue back together with StringBuilder, for example.

If you REALLY want, I'll edit my answer and break down exactly what it's doing if you need me to.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like homework that I don't want to do for you.  But I'll throw some stuff up here that will hopefully help you figure it out.

Your regex isn't going to match what you want.  `(.)` will capture a single character, and it won't capture new line characters.  So you'll have to fix that.  `+` matches one or more of the previous character set and `*` matches zero or more of the previous character.  Seems like you also want to make sure you're matching from `$` to `$`.  You're working inside Java strings so you have to escape it.

Try something like this for your regex:

```
final String pattern = "hhh me \\$([a-zA-Z\\s\n\r]*)\\$";
```

Then in Eclipse or in Java Docs look around the `Matcher` class for some helpful methods to find/replace matches you've got (The stuff inside `()` in a regular expression).

Maybe something like `Matcher.replaceFirst()` will help.